# Detect when users click on buttons in Youtube bar

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm sure this should to be quite easy, but I can't find the answer elsewhere...

I'm embedding a youtube (live) video on my domain through an iframe. I've managed to detect when the user clicks on the pause/play button using javascript events defined in  onYouTubeIframeAPIReady. I'd like to detect when the user clicks on the speaker icon (sound muted/sound on), on the fullscreen button, and also when he/she clicks on the "go to youtube" button.

Is this posisble?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize [Youtube Embed API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and [hide standard controls](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#controls) with `controls:0` option. Add [your own controls](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls) with all callbacks/event handlers you need.

Best option — you can use [Player Events](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events) and act accordingly. There is `onStateChange` available, so, you can detect and verify pause/unpause. Mute status can be verified too - you need to check muted status with `isMuted()` method constantly.

For Youtube button click I see this way to check - you can monitor window active state via `visibilitychange` and check iframe focus state to get video details (will not work in fullscreen I guess).

For fullscreen - [fullscreenchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenchange_event) event. In coupe with current active (playing) video you can check exact embedded video where fullscreen was clicked. Im not sure about the situation when fullscreen was clicked before play button was clicked by user.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer 350D. Sounds a bit like reinventing the wheel... There's no other way around?

Comment: @JoséL. check my updated answer.